# Работа с элементом checkedListBox

Tags: c#, winforms

Как пользователю, после компиляции, в `checkedListBox` устанавливать промежуточное состояние (серая галочка). 
Так как `checkedListBox1.SetItemCheckState(i, CheckState.Indeterminate);` уже программно ставит её.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Такой возможности нет. Промежуточное состояние можно задавать только программно. Из [документации](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.forms.checkedlistbox(v=vs.110).aspx):

> You must set the state of `Indeterminate` in the code because the user
>   interface for a `CheckedListBox` does not provide a mechanism to do
>   so.